# What are the http status codes for unsupported federation query

Tags: federation

In the [Federation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/federation.html) documentation it is explicitly mentioned that we should return `404` for a failed federation `name` lookup.

> Example: https://YOUR_FEDERATION_SERVER/federation?q=jed*stellar.org&type=name

What could be the `http` status codes if my server is not planning to support other lookups like `forward`, `id`, `txid`

Right now I am throwing a `404` with

```
{
    "detail": "We currently support `name` lookups only"
}
```

Is this fine?